# Calling procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

If we call a procedure inside a procedure like

```
procedure ter () is cursor XXXXX

another procedure load_ter()

another procedure load_value()

end ter;
```

Does it calls order wise inside the procedure. or it can be from anywhere

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. Could you explain it a little bit further, please? What is "another procedure"? Is it a standalone procedure, or is it local to the procedure TER? What does "or it can be (called?) from anywhere" mean? What is "anywhere"?

Comment: its a procedure calling inside the procedure...

Comment: well ter() is having two more procedure to get some values from that procedure

Comment: If you run procedure TER and call LOAD_TER, then LOAD_TER will execute until it finishes. Then LOAD_VALUE will be called, executed. Once it finishes, the rest of commands in TER will be run and - finally - TER will terminate as well.

Comment: ok thas perfect thats what i was looking for thank you..

Comment: can u write as an answer so that i can close the thread by marking it as right.

Comment: Sure; copy/pasted comment I wrote previously.

Comment: Seriously, you are asking what order the lines will be executed in? The order you coded them in. Have you observed something different?

Comment: It's difficult to answer a coding question like "how would this code work" if the code is not complete or wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run procedure `TER` and call `LOAD_TER`, then `LOAD_TER` will execute until it finishes. Then `LOAD_VALUE` will be called, executed. Once it finishes, the rest of commands in `TER` will be run and - finally - `TER` will terminate as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this procedure:

```
create or replace procedure demo as
begin
   dbms_output.put_line('One');
   dbms_output.put_line('Two');
   dbms_output.put_line('Three');
end demo;
```

the output will be (with dbms_output enabled):

```
One
Two
Three
```

That is, the instructions within a procedure will always executed in the order you coded them.

I have to wonder what prompted this question.